# Applying Featuretools output to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction, featuretools

I have a dataframe which the target features, which looks like this:

```
x x1 y
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

Now I use feautretools to automatically do feature engineering, using this line of code:

```
es = ft.EntitySet(id = 'x')
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'y', dataframe = df, index = 'x')
feature_matrix, feature_names = ft.dfs(entityset=es, 
target_entity = 'y', 
max_depth = 2, 
verbose = 1, 
n_jobs = 3)
```

I would like to take the features generated, and then apply them to a dataset which lacks the labels, something which looks like this:

```
x x1
1 2
```

How would I take the features generate (e.g mean of x + x1) and then map their creation process (`(df['x']+df['x1']).mean()`) onto the dataframe lacking the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answered my question, the saving feature part:
https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/deployment.html